Unhandled exception with data binding
Why does this markup:
<material:TabView TabPlacement="Start" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Instance.Collection, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainView}}}"/>

lead to this:
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
#endif

with the awesome error message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It's working if the collection is empty (:
The calling method is MoveNext.

When it breaks on the exception, inspect the values in e which will have more details probably about the stack trace and where the exception originates.
